# How to prove that the implicit function theorem implies the inverse function theorem?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

I can prove the converse of it, but I cannot do this one. Here is the problem:

> Prove that the implicit function theorem implies the inverse function theorem.

Comment: Why not post what problems your having or what you've tried? It really helps to know what an OP is struggling with exactly. Sometimes you might be misunderstanding something or not fully understanding something and answerers on here can bridge the gap or provide valuable insight. Like a guy said in a movie once "You gotta milk it" :) Otherwise, you could just find the proof on Google..

Comment: Oh... I missed that point. thanks for your advice! I will soon!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, consider $F : \mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ given by $F({\bf x}, {\bf y}) = f({\bf y}) - {\bf x}$.

Comment: Is it enough to prove for the certain form for the function like F(x,y)=f(y)-x=0 ?

Comment: And.. the general conditions of the implicit function Thm is... F:Rn x Rm -> Rm  . Is it okay to prove just for the F : Rn x Rn -> Rn?

Comment: Your post suggests you want to prove the inverse function theorem, given the implicit function theorem. Apply the implicit function theorem to the function I've suggested.

Comment: Wow!! It's solved! Thanks you!! It was very helpful. Thnaks you!

Comment: I thought you should have written $F(x,y)=y-f(x)$

Comment: @Arabbellypunching: I don't think so. Applying the implicit function theorem, for each point $(x_0, y_0)$ with $F(x_0, y_0) = 0$, there is an open set $U$ with $x_0 \in U$, and a function $g : U \to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $F(x, g(x)) = 0$ for all $x \in U$, i.e. $f(g(x)) = x$ for all $x \in U$.